# Group theory problem with 2 nonempty subsets

Tags: group-theory

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this problem:

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group with the identity element $e$. $H \neq G$ is a nonempty subset of $G$ with the property that for all $a \in H$ and $b \in G \setminus H$ we have $ab \in H$. Consider the following statements:

1. $\forall u,v \in H$ we have $uv \in H$
2. $\forall u,v \in G\setminus H$ we have $uv \in G \setminus H$
3. $e \in H$
4. $\forall x\in H$ we have $x^{-1}\in H$

Which of the statements are true?

---

3 is false because it would imply $b \in H $ and $b \in G\setminus H $, also if 4 is true, then 1 is clearly false.

As for the rest of the statements, I'm not sure how to prove or disprove them. I was thinking of proving 1 or 2 by contradiction, but im pretty sure my proof is wrong:

(for 2) suppose $\exists u,v \in G \setminus H$ such that $uv \in H$, then there exists $h \in H$ for which:

$uv=h$, multiplying by $a \in G \setminus H \Longleftrightarrow $  $u(va)=ha \in H $ (from hypothesis)

but since $v,a \in G \setminus H$, we have that  $va\in G\setminus H \Longrightarrow uva \in G\setminus H$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**claim 3:**  if $e\in H$ than there is $b\in G\backslash H$ (by assumption) such that $b=e\cdot b\in H$, and this is a condratiction, so calim 3 is false.

**claim 4:** now, claim 4 is true, other wise, if $x\in H$ and $x^{-1}\in G\backslash H$ than $e=x\cdot x^{-1}\in H$ which will prove claim 3, and we saw that it is false.

**claim 2:** if $u,v\in G\backslash H$ such that $u\cdot v\in H$, than $v^{-1}\in G\backslash H$, other wise $v^{-1}\in H$ and by claim 4 we will get that $v=\left(v^{-1}\right)^{-1}\in H$, so by the property of $H$ we know that $u=(u\cdot v)\cdot v^{-1}\in H$, which is a contradiction.

**claim 1:** by claim 4 we know that if $x\in H$ than $x^{-1}\in H$, so if claim 1 is true, we will get that $e=x\cdot x^{-1}\in H$ but we saw that claim three is false.

in summary, only claim 4 is true and all other claims are always false.

Comment: Udi posted the same time as me, and his argument for the 2nd claim works, while mine was botched. However, I want to leave my counter-example for the first claim here. The group $\left(\mathbb{N},+\right)$ has a non-empty subset $H:=\{\text{odd numbers}\}$. Notice that $0 \notin H$, and any odd number added with an even number is in $H$. The addition of 2 odd numbers is even, so not in $H$, so 1 must be false. I just want to say that sometime we do not need to jump immediately to abstract proofs, and we can 'feel out' which direction we should try to prove the statement (by using examples)

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes, I am agreeing with you, when i started to think about this question i looked at the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and took $H=\{1\}$, which work as well. but it was also very interesting to see if this is a claim which one can disprove just from the axioms of group theory and the assumption of the question.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun your comment on the question seems to imply that he should ask 4 questions. These questions likely come as a packet, and should be treated as so. If he asked a single question instead, it would be voted down or closed or ignored since it's too trivial. I don't know if he edited it, but he did attempt the question, so please let it be. Everyone was once new to mathematics, and new to this website. A lot of hawkishness in mathematics gives it it's reputation.